# How to print the result of a method in a file with Java

Tags: java, file, methods, void

Is there any way to print a result of a void method into a file in Java. For example, for this method below, I want to print the result in a file : *file.txt* not in console. Is that possible?

```
public void Message(String s){
    System.out.Print("Your message is: "+s);
}
```

And thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: What you need is file.io.  Which is too much to explain in a comment.  So here's a link:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it, but it will override the content each time :

```
 public static void Message(String s) throws IOException {
   File file = new File("put_the_path_of_your_file_here");
   FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

   fileWriter.write(s);
   fileWriter.flush();
   fileWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `PrintStream` instance that writes to a file and use that instead of `System.out`, which is just a `PrintStream` that goes to the console.

```
public void Message(String s){
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream("/path/to/your/file");
    p.print("Your message is: " + s);
    p.close();
}
```